# Efficient way to get a k-subset from a list of numbers in which numbers are at least d apart?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, subset

Say I have a list of 10 numbers as below

```
lst = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 20, 27, 28, 30, 40]
```

I want to get **one** subset of `k` numbers, in which every pair of numbers are at least different from each other by a distance `d`. Right now I am using `itertools.combinations`, and the code is working fine for small lists.

```
from itertools import combinations

def k_subset_at_least_d_apart(nums, k, d):
    for subset in combinations(nums, k):
        a = sorted(subset)
        if min([t - s for s, t in zip(a, a[1:])]) >= d:
            return subset
    return None
```

For example, if I want to get a subset of 5 with numbers at least 6 apart from each other:

```
subset = k_subset_at_least_d_apart(lst, k=5, d=6)
print(subset)
# (1, 10, 20, 27, 40)
```

However, my code becomes too slow when I want to e.g. get a subset of 20 numbers from a list of 50 numbers in which numbers are at least 10 apart. Can anyone suggest a relatively fast algorithm that can first determine whether such subset exists or not, then finds one subset? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How big is your potential input size?

Comment: @DanielHao Something like getting a subset of 100 from a list of 300 numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure; you can just greedily repeat the step of taking the smallest valid element:

```py
def k_subset_at_least_d_apart(nums, k, d):
    last = -float('inf')
    answer = []
    for element in sorted(nums):
        if element - last >= d:
            answer.append(element)
            last = element
            if len(answer) == k:
                return answer
    return None
```

If nums aren't presorted, it's hard to do (asymptotically) much better than this code, which takes `O(n log n)` time. You can get an `O(n*k)` algorithm with k repeated passes, which may be faster depending on n and k. If they are sorted, you can do the 'greedily take min valid', but with a binary search to find the next smallest valid element, for an `O(k log n)` algorithm.

Proof of the greedy algorithm:

Suppose the greedy algorithm gives a solution `G = g0, g1, ... gm` and an optimal (length-k) solution is given by `A = a0, a1, ... a_(k-1)`, with `m <= k-1` (both in sorted, increasing order).

Let `i` be the smallest index where `ai != gi`. If i is 0, we must have `g0 < a0`, since `g0` is `min(nums)`, so we can replace `a0` with `g0` in A for another optimal solution `A' = g0, a1, ... a_(k-1)`. Otherwise, for i > 0, (details left as an exercise, but very similar to above), if `a0 == g0, a1 == g1 ... a_(i-1)==g_(i-1)`, we can also replace `ai` with `gi` to get another optimal solution.

Eventually we get that there exists an optimal solution `A*` such that `G` is a prefix of `A*`, then we can argue by contradiction that if `G` has length below `k` and is a proper prefix of an optimal solution, the greedy algorithm would have extended `G` when it saw the  element `a_(m+1)`.

Comment: The problem with greedy algorithm is that many times it will return None even if there exists quite some valid subsets. I want to accurately know if such subset exist or not

Comment: @ShaunHan Sorry, but I don't think that's correct. The greedy algorithm will always give a solution if any exists. To see why, note that this problem can be reduced to [interval scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling); replace every array element x with an interval [x, x+d]. This is doing the same as an "Earliest Deadline First" scheduling algorithm. There's also probably much simpler proofs of why this works using an exchange argument. If you do have a counterexample, please let me know.

Comment: Wouldn't one proof that this works be: for any optimal solution with elements between indexes `i` and `j` in the sorted array with lowest element `A[i]`, we can always replace `A[i]` with `A[i-1]`? (cc @ShaunHan)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I've included a fuller proof in the post. It's basically what you posted, but in more detail. It's possible that your proof is full, but I don't know how to prove the algorithm's correctness without either loop invariants or the full exchange argument on prefixes of solutions.

Comment: @kcsquared Thanks. I am convinced after reading your proof. As a side question, I think a greedy algorithm only works for 1D case right? For example, if I want find a k-subset from a set of 3D points that are at least apart by a Euclidean distance d, how would you approach this problem?

Comment: @ShaunHan Yes, that is correct. Once you move to even 2 dimensions, the problem becomes NP-complete. However, you can still efficiently approximate solutions for this case, which might be enough for your needs. The specific problem name in 2D is "Maximum independent set" on a [Unit disk graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk_graph); I haven't found a common name for the 3D version of this graph family, but the best solution to that problem deserves a separate question.